# Custom UINavigationBar from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, navigationbar, uiapplicationdelegate

I made a custom UINavigationBar and I would like to use it globally. I see in other examples that for setting UINavigationBar appearance globally, you have to do something like this  `let navigationBar  = UINavigationBar.appearance()` in the AppDelegate. Then you can set up the the properties. In my case, I have set up all the properties in `class var` like so:

```
extension UINavigationBar {
    class var customNavBar : UINavigationBar{
        let navigationBar = UINavigationBar()
        navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir-Black", size: 40)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.RED]

        //gets rid of black separation bar
        navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .any, barMetrics: .default)

        //set the background color to white
        navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        return navigationBar
    }
}
```

Now, how can I set the UINavigationBar from AppDelegate to inherent these properties. I mean having something like this in the app delegate. Or similar of course.
In AppDelegate:

```
let navigationBar  = UINavigationBar.customNavBar.appearance()
```

The reason I would like to do this is because I have some other `UIViewControllers` (that do not segue from my `TabViewController`), where I would like to manually add the a UINavigationBar and it has to look just like the custom one.

Comment: Are you setting the properties of UINavigationBar.appearance() ? e.g. UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .red

Comment: @andrehungaro indeed, but I would like to instead call my customNavBar in my app delegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was wrong 
In swift you should use

```
NavController = UINavigationController.init(navigationBarClass: yoursubClass, toolbarClass: AnyClass?)
```

Then

```
if let window = self.window{
        window.rootViewController = NavController
 }
```

[reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621866-init)

Comment: how about in swift?

Comment: I understand what you are doing now, however my problem is that I already have a navigationcontroller assigned to the rootviewcontroller. It is actually a TabViewController

Comment: Yeah just use init() method above and assign it to your custom nav bar

Comment: not sure I'm following you. Here's what I have window?.rootViewController = MenuTabBarController(), where class MenuTabBarController: UITabBarController

Comment: Check this https://medium.com/@ITZDERR/uinavigationcontroller-and-uitabbarcontroller-programmatically-swift-3-d85a885a5fd0

Comment: So exactly what I said then.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to customise your navigation bar to that degree, you might be better off making a subclass.  The catch is that you will need to manually pass the class name into any navigation controllers that need to use it.  You can do the same for a `UIToolbar` if you need to, or pass `nil` to use the default.

```
class MyNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        // configure your nav bar here
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

let navController = UINavigationController(navigationBarClass: MyNavigationBar.self, toolbarClass: nil)
```

For reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621866-init

Comment: how can I use MyNavigationBar in the AppDelegate, so that it replaces the NavigationBar at the app level?

Comment: Not all apps have a `UINavigationController`.  Are you using storyboards?

Comment: I assume then that you are creating the app-wide navigation controller in your `AppDelegate` and setting it as `window.rootViewController` or something similar.

Comment: So use that last line of code in my example to create your navigation controller.